# Cannot require file in application.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to simplify our configuration by creating small configuration classes that can be included in our application.rb.

**lib/logging.rb**

```
class << Logging

    def configure(config)
        # ... configure logging stuff
    end

end
```

**application.rb**

```
require 'lib'
module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application

      Logging.configure(config)

  end
end
```

The problem is if I don't use `require "lib"` then I get an `Undefined Constant Logging` error. But if I try to require it I get:

```
bin/rails:6: warning: already initialized constant APP_PATH
/opt/qtip/bin/rails:6: warning: previous definition of APP_PATH was here
```

The only way I've been able to get it to work is by doing this which is very limiting.

```
config.autoload_paths = %w(lib)

config.after_initialize do
  ::Logging.configure(config)
end
```

Comment: Is the `config` you pass in the one in-scope in application.rb? I would probably rethink the design, as it is like handing someone your wallet/purse so they can rummage through it to see your ID: only give the minimum information to your classes as is necessary to do their job. Also, I would add that to an initializer instead of in application.rb: `config/initializers/logging.rb` with `require 'lib/logging'; Logging.configure(config)`.

Comment: First of all if I move it to `config/initializers/logging.rb` `require 'lib/logging'` shouldn't work but if I try it I still get the same `APP_PATH` error. And as for the passing in "config" I'm really just trying to move a bunch of stuff that is cluttering up the application.rb in to discrete classes that focus on configuring that one thing so I want it to have access to the `config` object.

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong class declaration.

Instead

```
class << Logging
```

you should use

```
class Logging
  class << self
    def configure(config)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: `class << Logging` is for a singleton I believe or a `static class` so it's not something that should be instantiated.

Comment: @Philidor Green I know it, but before reference to constant this constant should be defined

Comment: I've changed the class definition as you stated, and it's in `lib/logging.rb`. How do I require it and use it?